# Enabling the back button without allowing manual changes through the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, pushstate

I have a jQuery Mobile application I'm developing. jQuery Mobile uses `pushState` by default to allow the browser's back button to work dynamically.

Now, my application is meant to change its pages dynamically, and the user should always arrive at the front page when loading the application.

The problem is, jQuery Mobile updates the page's hash in the URL whenever I go to a page in the application. Now, if the user enters the same hash in the application, jQuery Mobile will automatically take them to that page (when I'd want them to be handled by my code). Also, if they refresh the page, I'd like my code to take them back to where they should be, not directly moved to the hash the URL had.

To prevent this, I tried to add the following code in the `mobileinit` event:

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

This works, but it also disables the `pushState` updates, which in turn breaks the back button, which I don't want to happen.

What would be the best way to allow users to use the back button while still not allowing manual movement between pages?

Comment: You've invested 100 of your rep on this question; you've got two answers, did they help you fixing your problem?

Answer (score 6):

I don't have so much element to describe a possible and accurate solution for your problem, but an easy one should be this:

on every link on your page that take to another one attach a function like this:

```
$(DOMElem).on("click",function(){
  sessionStorage["urlChangedByLink"] = "true";
});
```

On the same page you can try if there are no problem with this:

```
$( window ).on( "navigate", function( event, data ) {
  if(sessionStorage["urlChangedByLink"] == "true")
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = true;
  else
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
```

Or this, on the other page you check if this storage variable exsist and than make your operation:

```
if(sessionStorage["urlChangedByLink"] == "true")
  continue navigation...
else
  window.history.back();
```

Comment: an excellent suggestion Emanuele! I've used localStorage in the past to assist me in my navigation woes. I had to navigate a directory, so I stored the 3-digit code for the district so I always knew where I was!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a place where you set sessionStorage["urlChangedByLink"] to false? otherwise it will be always true. I guess at the end of window navigate handler we should set it to false.

Comment: Incorrect. This doesn't cover refreshing current page nor accessing pages manually with hash. I wonder why users upvote a totally wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

one option here is to set the `data-url` for each of your pages you simply add the attribute to your page `div` and set it equal to your home page that way the url for the page shown in the history doesnt have the hash values (or you could include your own values). the documentation on this is better explained [in the jquery mobile documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/#page-data-url)